# DataCenter Certification

Tags: datacenter

What kind of acceditations exist for a datacenter?

I am not asking about process accreditation. Not ITIL, not ISO 20000. I am asking about an accreditation for the datacenter itself.

As far as I can see there is "Uptime Institute". They are giving "Tier"s based on DC design and/or implementation.

Anyone else you know of ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For people - http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/le3/le2/le41/le99/learning_certification_type_home.html

For DCs itself - http://ssae16.com/ (SSAE 16 is the U.S. successor to SAS70. ISAE 3402 is the International equivalent)

Although not a 'DC' accreditation directly, a lot of datacenters generally have PCI compliance accreditation (PCI DSS).

Comment: That's for people, not datacenters.

Comment: oops good catch!

Comment: I don't believe a DC can be PCI compliant - I understand PCI-DSS compliance to also require user training, security controls (access, physical, and data), process & procedure, etc. Securing the DC is part of attaining compliance, but you could still stick an insecure server in there and thus not be PCI compliant.

Comment: correct mfinni, OP was asking for different types of accreditation, hence i added that it was not directly a DC accreditation but rather 'add-value' to DC

Comment: SSAE16 and ISAE 3402 are still "process" certifications.  As they are usually audits of the data center's controls and processes.  They do not dictate specific controls like Uptime Institute does (e.g. multiple power providers).  However, it is still very useful as it gives a third-party auditor's opinion of the controls in place.

Answer (score 3):

Look into SAS 70 Compliance if you want to host 'high value' resources in said Data Center.

Basic Overview:

http://www.sas70.us.com/industries/data-center-colocations.php

Answer (score 2):

There is a certification for a "secure data centre" by TÜV Saarland. They have TIER-style criteria as well, salted with some additions from the German BSI (federal agency for IT security).

TÜV INTERCERT is a subsidiary apparently marketing an [internationalized version of this certificate](http://www.tuv-intercert.org/en/our-services/product/certification-data-centre.html), a couple of [published presentation slides](http://www.gaccny.com/fileadmin/ahk_gaccny/Consulting/Green_Corner/Offshore_Presentation_TUV_Intercert.pdf) have some more details.